# Would like to install Eclipse for c/c++ for windows 8.1

Tags: c++, c, ide

A little confused about which Eclispe for c/c++. I am thinking of using
the cygwin compiler. Not sure if Eclipse have its own compiler. Would like
help with installation, started to install cygwin but could not figure
some of install options.

Comment: I used the Eclipse CDT before. I actually hated it. It doesn't provide the nice error identification and suggestion features that Eclipse for Java does. I would recommend using a virtual machine with Linux and that will give you a C compiler built in plus access to a very large variety of dev tools. In short, developing C and C++ on Windows is a huge pain.

Comment: Try this? https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

Comment: Eclipse is a remarkably terrible IDE mostly geared towards Java.  Use free Visual Studio Express.  Visual Studio has edit and continue, a great watch window and a million other things.  And if for some reason you want a more GCC/mingw/Linuxy compiler, use CodeBlocks instead of Eclipse and you won't even need Cygwin.  http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe  <--- 2 clicks and your done.  CodeBlocks projects can easily be used on Linux, like the same project file.  Eclipse is out-of-this-world bad, even compared to other bad IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely get [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/marsr). It's developed by the eclipse team themselves and is optimized for C/C++.

Also, eclipse comes with a compiler. Just make sure you create a "Managed Make" C++ project